# Access violation with GLFW/GLEW program?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I get this error when trying to draw a triangle with OpenGL:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Project3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000. occurred
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    glewInit();
    //if (glewInit != GLEW_OK)
    //  std::cout << "ew";
    /* Initialize the library */
    if( !glfwInit() )
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL );
    if( !window )
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    float poss[ 6 ] =
    {
        -0.5, -0.5,
        0.0,   0.5,
        0.5, -0.5
    };
    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof( float ), poss, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers( window );

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at your post in the preview section before posting and check if everything looks OK. Is the code indented properly? Are there enough paragraphs? If it doesn't, work on it until you feel like it is easy to read and understand. Also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to write good questions. This will increase your chances of someone actually answering your question by a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Call (not evaluate the address of!) `glewInit()` *after* `glfwMakeContextCurrent()`.  Otherwise all the OpenGL function pointers declared by `glew.h` will remain NULL since `glewInit()` requires a current GL context to operate correctly.

Granted your program *still* won't draw anything after you fix that (due to missing vertex array enablement & pointer setting) but that's a separate issue.